# Generic maximum/minimum function for complex numbers

Tags: julia

In julia, one can find (supposedly) efficient implementations of the `min`/`minimum` and `max`/`maximum` over collections of real numbers.
As these concepts are not uniquely defined for complex numbers, I was wondering if a parametrized version of these functions was already implemented somewhere.

I am currently sorting elements of the array of interest, then taking the last value, which is as far as I know, much more costly than finding the value with the maximum absolute value (or something else).

This is mostly to reproduce the Matlab behavior of the `max` function over complex arrays.

Here is my current code

```
a = rand(ComplexF64,4)
b = sort(a,by  = (x) -> abs(x))
c = b[end]
```

The probable function call would look like

```
c = maximum/minimum(a,by=real/imag/abs/phase)
```

**EDIT** Some performance tests in Julia 1.5.3 with the provided solutions

```
function maxby0(f,iter)
    b = sort(iter,by  = (x) -> f(x))
    c = b[end]
end

function maxby1(f, iter)
    reduce(iter) do x, y
        f(x) > f(y) ? x : y
    end
end

function maxby2(f, iter; default = zero(eltype(iter)))
    isempty(iter) && return default
    res, rest = Iterators.peel(iter)
    fa = f(res)
    for x in rest
        fx = f(x)
        if fx > fa
            res = x
            fa = fx
        end
    end

    return res
end

compmax(CArray) = CArray[ (abs.(CArray) .== maximum(abs.(CArray))) .& (angle.(CArray) .== maximum( angle.(CArray))) ][1]


Main.isless(u1::ComplexF64, u2::ComplexF64) = abs2(u1) < abs2(u2)

function maxby5(arr)
    arr_max = arr[argmax(map(abs, arr))]
end

a = rand(ComplexF64,10)

using BenchmarkTools
@btime maxby0(abs,$a)
@btime maxby1(abs,$a)
@btime maxby2(abs,$a)
@btime compmax($a)
@btime maximum($a)
@btime maxby5($a)
```

Output for a vector of length 10:

```
>841.653 ns (1 allocation: 240 bytes)
>214.797 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
>118.961 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
>Execution fails
>20.340 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
>144.444 ns (1 allocation: 160 bytes)
```

Output for a vector of length 1000:

```
>315.100 μs (1 allocation: 15.75 KiB)
>25.299 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
>12.899 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
>Execution fails
>1.520 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
>14.199 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
```

Output for a vector of length 1000 (with all comparisons made with `abs2`):

```
>35.399 μs (1 allocation: 15.75 KiB)
>3.075 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
>1.460 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
>Execution fails
>1.520 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
>2.211 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
```

Some remarks :

- Sorting clearly (and as expected) slows the operations
- Using `abs2` saves a lot of performance (expected as well)

To conclude :

- As a built-in function will provide this in 1.7, I will avoid using the additional `Main.isless` method, though it is all things considered the most performing one, to not modify the core of my julia
- The `maxby1` and `maxby2` allocate nothing
- The `maxby1` feels more readable

the winner is therefore Andrej Oskin!

**EDIT n°2** a new benchmark using the corrected `compmax` implementation

```
julia> @btime maxby0(abs2,$a)
  36.799 μs (1 allocation: 15.75 KiB)
julia> @btime maxby1(abs2,$a)
  3.062 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
julia> @btime maxby2(abs2,$a)
  1.160 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
julia> @btime compmax($a)
  26.899 μs (9 allocations: 12.77 KiB)
julia> @btime maximum($a)
  1.520 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
julia> @btime maxby5(abs2,$a)
2.500 μs (4 allocations: 8.00 KiB)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Julia 1.7 you can use `argmax`

```
julia> a = rand(ComplexF64,4)
4-element Vector{ComplexF64}:
  0.3443509906876845 + 0.49984979589871426im
  0.1658370274750809 + 0.47815764287341156im
  0.4084798173736195 + 0.9688268736875587im
 0.47476987432458806 + 0.13651720575229853im

julia> argmax(abs2, a)
0.4084798173736195 + 0.9688268736875587im
```

Since it will take some time to get to 1.7, you can use the following analog

```
maxby(f, iter) = reduce(iter) do x, y
                   f(x) > f(y) ? x : y
                 end
julia> maxby(abs2, a)
0.4084798173736195 + 0.9688268736875587im
```

UPD: slightly more efficient way to find such maximum is to use something like

```
function maxby(f, iter; default = zero(eltype(iter)))
    isempty(iter) && return default
    res, rest = Iterators.peel(iter)
    fa = f(res)
    for x in rest
        fx = f(x)
        if fx > fa
            res = x
            fa = fx
        end
    end

    return res
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify a bit. You mean that `argmax` currently has not method handling a function as argument ?

Comment: Also, what would be the right way to pass a `dims` option to this `maxby` ?

Comment: Yes, there is no function as an argument in 1.5 (and I think 1.6).

The easiest way for dims is to iterate over CartesianIndices, I think. Never done it myself, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

According to octave's documentation (which presumably mimics matlab's behaviour):

```
 For complex arguments, the magnitude of the elements are used for
 comparison.  If the magnitudes are identical, then the results are
 ordered by phase angle in the range (-pi, pi].  Hence,

      max ([-1 i 1 -i])
          => -1

 because all entries have magnitude 1, but -1 has the largest phase
 angle with value pi.
```

Therefore, if you'd like to mimic matlab/octave functionality *exactly*, then based on this logic, I'd construct a 'max' function for complex numbers as:

```
function compmax( CArray )
    Absmax   = CArray[   abs.(CArray) .== maximum(  abs.(CArray)) ]
    Totalmax = Absmax[ angle.(Absmax) .== maximum(angle.(Absmax)) ]
    return Totalmax[1]
end
```

(adding appropriate typing as desired).

Examples:

```
Nums0 = [ 1, 2, 3 + 4im, 3 - 4im, 5 ];   compmax( Nums0 )
# 1-element Array{Complex{Int64},1}:
#  3 + 4im

Nums1 = [ -1, im, 1, -im ];   compmax( Nums1 )
# 1-element Array{Complex{Int64},1}:
#  -1 + 0im
```

Comment: While your implementation works fine on your examples, it seems it doesn't systematically work for randomly selected complex numbers...

Comment: @BambOo you're right, I had a bug in the logic (applying maximum angle to the full array rather to the subset that is already of maximum magnitude). Fixed now. Though obviously, as per the accepted answer, if you don't care about matlab-compatible behaviour then following this logic isn't particularly important. :)

Comment: Let's say I'd rather have the possibility to have a default behaviour yet be able to change it when desired. In matlab there is actually no mention of the phase in such comparisons, though matlab probable has a behavior for this too.

Comment: @BambOo yes, octave is clearer about it in their documentation. Matlab 'implies' this is what it does in the examples it provides, but does not make it too explicit that this is their specification ...

Comment: @BambOo btw, out of interest, could you rerun your benchmark with the corrected function? I'm curious how unoptimised this is, hahah.

Comment: Just added, not very efficient compared to the others yet better than my own :)

Answer (score 5):

If this was a code for my computations, I would have made my life much simpler by:

```
julia> Main.isless(u1::ComplexF64, u2::ComplexF64) = abs2(u1) < abs2(u2)

julia> maximum(rand(ComplexF64, 10))
0.9876138798492835 + 0.9267321874614858im
```

This adds a new implementation for an existing method in `Main`. Therefore for a library code it is not an elegant idea, but it will you get where you need it with the least effort.

Answer (score 4):

The "size" of a complex number is determined by the size of its modulus. You can use abs for that. Or get 1.7 as [Andrej Oskin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1494135/andrej-oskin) said.

```
julia> arr = rand(ComplexF64, 10)
10-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
 0.12749588414783353 + 0.09918182087026373im
  0.7486501790575264 + 0.5577981676269863im
  0.9399200789666509 + 0.28339836191094747im
  0.9695470502095325 + 0.9978696209350371im
  0.6599207157942191 + 0.0999992072342546im
 0.30059521996405425 + 0.6840859625686171im
 0.22746651600614132 + 0.33739559003514885im
  0.9212471084010287 + 0.2590484924393446im
    0.74848598947588 + 0.41129443181449554im
  0.8304447441317468 + 0.8014240389454632im
```

```
julia> arr_max = arr[argmax(map(abs, arr))]
0.9695470502095325 + 0.9978696209350371im
```

```
julia> arr_min = arr[argmin(map(abs, arr))]
0.12749588414783353 + 0.09918182087026373im
```

Comment: Though the "size" of a complex number i.e. its norm is uniquely defined, sorting complex numbers is not

Comment: You can also use broadcasting instead of map. For performance reasons, abs2 is better than abs because taking a square root is expensive.

` arr[argmax(abs2.(arr))]`

Comment: @BambOo honestly asking, why not? Seems to me like the natural way of sorting regular old numbers by magnitude/size/abs would be appropriate for complex as well. Is there a mathematical reason why this is not true? Are you implying that sorting complex "lexicographically" would be more appropriate?

Comment: @blorgon I would also tend to use the magnitude of the complex number. However, I was quite convinced by the discussions in here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22807/how-can-i-get-maximum-complex-value-from-an-array-of-complex-values524289-in-p. And as it is probably as difficult to implement a function for the magnitude, why not leave the user with the possibility to sort as needed

Comment: If in your use case, sorting real numbers by `abs` makes sense, then sorting complex numbers by norm  is fine. You may be interested in the stability of the sorting though ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts ).